# Why does Google make an @class forward declaration in an implementation (.m) file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been using [GDataXMLNode.m](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/XMLSupport/GDataXMLNode.m) provided by Google in Objective-C, and I've noticed that they do an `@class` forward declaration in their implementation (.m) file. They do this:

```
@class NSArray, NSDictionary, NSError, NSString, NSURL;
```

Why is this? Is there any real optimisation created by doing this?

Comment: My guess is that it was some sort of documentation standard.  Poorly enforced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they play any role in compilation, since they are present as well in the `.h` file, so they are simply a duplicate. Furthermore, the `.h` file already import `Foundation.h`, thus those forward declarations are simply redundant.

Maybe they are used as a form of documentation of dependencies that `GDataXMLNode` has with other classes.

Comment: I would love to agree with you, but this is Google: I'm trusting that they do something like this for a reason, not just 'because they can', or simply a duplication someone missed...

Comment: The fact is that *it is* a duplication: those declarations already appear in the `.h` file *and* `NSString` also appears in `Foundation.h`. Both files end up being imported into the `.m` file. so the question is: what is the effect of duplicating the same forward declaration? I think none. I would understand your doubt if the forward declaration only appeared in the `.m` file, but it is not the case. google is google, but evidence is evidence... :-)

Comment: @nathanwhite - Have you seen the Android design?  Lots of things there that go against reason.  (They missed NSCharacterSet, NSMutableArray, and likely some others.)

Comment: @sergio I do appreciate what you're saying.

Comment: @HotLicks I can't say that I've spent much time in the Android design. Ok, I will take it at face value and assume, unless otherwise stated, that it is to no benefit.

Thanks guys

Comment: Forward declaration of system classes is pointless.  Just import the framework header, as Apple intended.   Dup'ing is more pointless still.   It is bad coding style likely either from a misguided attempt at documenting the code or a vestige of someone's learning efforts.